# Shape of Defect Density Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

A factory manufactures a part in 5 different sizes ${(A, B, C, D, E)}$, each with a different surface area ${(S_A, S_B, S_C, S_D, S_E)}$. The process is otherwise identical.

The number of defects detected on a part size can be modelled by a Poisson distribution, e.g. $D_A \sim Poiss(\lambda_A)$.

To compare between part sizes, Defect Density ($DD = {D_A}/{S_A}$) is calculated.

What is the shape of the overall Defect Density distribution?

Using genuine recorded data, JMP suggests a lognormal distribution, why?